# artifactId equivalent in Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle

I see in my default `build.gradle`, generated by `IDEA`, that group and version were set with:

```
group 'com.mycompany.mytopic'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

How to set artifact id?

In `Maven` I would write:

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.mytopic</groupId>
<artifactId>my-snippets</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

How to do the same in `Gradle`?

I saw advise to write

```
rootProject.name = 'my-snippets'
```

but why?

Why don't we write

```
rootProject.group 'com.inthemoon.snippets'
rootProject.version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default of artifactId is the `project name` in setting.gradle you can set the `project name` like below:

```
rootProject.name = "something"
```

or you can change it by putting below code in your build.gradle file

```
publishing {
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
       artifactId 'your_desired_name'
       from components.java
    }
}
```